# Getting started with the Acumatica API

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to get started with the Acumatica API using VB.net.  Is there a good place where I can find a tutorial or sample code?  Thanks...

Comment: Acumatica does have their [own documentation](https://www.acumatica.com/developer-resources/), that includes some code examples as well. There are differences between versions, so keep that in mind, to ensure the correct information is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Acumatica.com/developers page and find training and examples.
The link for training is here:
https://www.acumatica.com/acumatica-developer-training/

There is a set of training related to Web Services / API on this page.